# python equivalent of java Matcher.quoteReplacement()

Tags: python, regex

Python has [`re.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) if you want to match an arbitrary string literal.

In my case, however, I want to use an arbitrary string literal as a *replacement* string in [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub). The `re.escape()` method produces excessive escaping for that, but an unescaped literal string is not safe to use, because there are still special characters.

Is there an equivalent of Java's [`Matcher.quoteReplacement()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is the only "special" character in a replacement, according to the [re.sub documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

There's only one *obvious* way to do it, plus a non-obvious but documented way:

```
>>> repl = r"foo\1bar\2zot"
>>> re.sub(r".*", repl, "frobozz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
[snip]
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference
>>> re.sub(r".*", repl.replace("\\", "\\\\"), "frobozz")
'foo\\1bar\\2zot'
>>> re.sub(r".*", lambda z: repl, "frobozz")
'foo\\1bar\\2zot'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't `repl = repl.replace('\\','\\\\')` suffice?

Comment: I think so... can I be sure of this? Are there any other magic characters in the replacement string besides a backslash?

Comment: +1. As @sln said, there's also the `\g<n>` syntax, but escaping the backslash takes care of that, too.